# Querying data using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I've been playing around with XDocument and LINQ. I've managed to get a file to write:

```
<SchoolData storeName="mikveIsrael" location="mikve">
    <employee>
        <personalInfo>
            <name>Ilan Berlinbluv</name>
            <zip>58505</zip>
        </personalInfo>
        <employeeInfo>
            <salary>5000</salary>
            <id>1</id>
        </employeeInfo>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <personalInfo>
            <name>Noam Inbar</name>
            <zip>58504</zip>
        </personalInfo>
        <employeeInfo>
            <salary>4500</salary>
            <id>2</id>
        </employeeInfo>
    </employee>
</SchoolData>
```

I've been trying to read the value using this code:

```
public void QueryDoc(XDocument doc)
{
    var data = (from item in doc.Descendants("employee")
               select new {
                   name = item.Element("personalInfo").Element("name").Value,
                   salary = item.Element("employeeInfo").Element("salary").Value,
                   ID = item.Element("employeeInfo").Element("ID").Value,
                   zip = item.Element("personalInfo").Element("zip").Value
                   });
        foreach (var p in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
        }
    }
```

However when I try and run the code, it gives me an exception: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
I've been following [this tutorial](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/10/understanding-c-simple-linq-to.html), and on their screen it works, however on mine it doesn't.

Comment: personalinfo tag doesn't have ID in it?

Comment: True, but still error. (I edited the code)

Comment: Why not simply remove .Element("xxx").Value from all and check is there is null anywhere? Then add Element and check again.

Comment: @Ilan321, elements are case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ID = item.Element("personalInfo").Element("ID").Value,
```

should be

```
ID = item.Element("employeeInfo").Element("id").Value,
```

You're querying the wrong element, which will return a `null` value and throw a `NullPointerException` when you use `.Value` on it.

Comment: See Mokchhya's comment. I edited the code, but the error is still the same.

Comment: @Ilan321: even with lowercase 'id'?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
ID = item.Element("personalInfo").Element("ID").Value,
```

will fail because the element `ID` is not present in `personalInfo`